# SSR 2016 Report pagination

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

I have a problem with my paginated report and I need help. I have three parameters in my design and whenever I run it, the parameters don't ever appear on the reports. I have tried it in different ways but the result always comes back to me same way. Please could anyone help me with this? Even when I click the parameter pane, the parameters are nowhere to be found.

I have also deleted it several times but still does not work.

Comment: Hi, can you check if they have been set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just try to run it on the preview mode? if so you just need **to close the SSDT and reopen it**

Comment: It looks like they are using Report Builder; not SSDT.

Comment: whatever BIDS you're using ;)